# Modular transformation of affine characters of non-simply connected groups$.$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, modular-forms, characters, conformal-field-theory

Consider an (untwisted) affine algebra corresponding to a compact and simply-connected Lie group $G$. Under a modular transformation, its characters transform as (cf. [9612078](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9612078))
$$
\chi_\mu\to\sum_{\nu\in P^k_+}S^G_{\mu\nu}\chi_{\nu}\tag{3.6}
$$
where the so-called modular $S$-matrix is given by the Kac-Peterson formula,
$$
S^G_{\lambda\mu}=i^{|\Delta_+|}|M^*/kM|^{-1/2}\sum_{w\in W}\epsilon(w)\mathrm e^{-2\pi i (\lambda+\rho,w(\mu+\rho))/h}\tag{3.7}
$$
where $M$ is the root lattice of $G$; $M^*$ its dual; and $W$ the Weyl group of $\mathfrak g$.

> How do we construct the $S$-matrix for an affine algebra corresponding to the non-simply connected group $G/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma\subseteq Z(G)$ is a discrete subgroup of the centre of $G$?

For example, given $S^{\mathrm{SU}(N)}$ or $S^{\mathrm{Spin}(N)}$, how do we calculate $S^{\mathrm{PSU}(N):=\mathrm{SU}(N)/\mathbb Z_N}$ or $S^{\mathrm{SO}(N):=\mathrm{Spin}(N)/\mathbb Z_2}$?

The integrable representations of $G/\Gamma$ can be thought of as equivalence classes of integrable representations of $G$, by identifying any two that are in the same $\Gamma$-orbit. Therefore, it seems reasonable for me to expect a formula of the form
$$
S^{G/\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}\overset?=\frac{1}{|\mu||\nu|}\sum_{\substack{\mu'\in\mu\\\nu'\in\nu}}S_{\mu'\nu'}^G
$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the orbit of the corresponding weight. This is manifestly independent of the representative we choose for $\mu,\nu$, and it reduces to $S^G$ if $\Gamma$ is trivial. A preliminary computation in Mathematica seems to suggest that this formula is not quite correct (e.g., $SS^*$ is not the identity, but almost: it has some sporadic $2\times2$ blocks along the diagonal; therefore $S$ is *almost* unitary). My gut tells me that a similar formula should hold, but I haven't been able to derive it myself nor to find it online.

Comment: x-posted on physics.SE: [What is the modular $S$ matrix of non-simply-connected groups?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413334/84967).

Comment: These are simple current extensions of the simply connected versions, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02968 How to obtain the S-matrix for simple currents is well-known and goes back to I guess Schellekens

Comment: Here is the original reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601078